# Electrum address syncronization

Tags: json-rpc, api, electrum, balance

I need to periodically check the balance of a number of bitcoin addresses (a few tens or hundreds addresses).
I noticed that Electrum may syncronize a thousand or more imported addresses in a matter of a few seconds. But I failed to realise how it is done searching through Electrum source code.

Which methods it uses? Does it really import all these addresses into currently connected remote node and then calls `listunspent` no matter how many addresses I insert into the wallet?

Can you please point me to a code snippet that implements such funtionality

Answer (score 1):

Electrum wallet requires a special *Electrum compatible server* where it can query the data needed.

There are now several implementations eg:

- https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server
- https://github.com/chris-belcher/electrum-personal-server
- https://github.com/kyuupichan/electrumx

> ...code snippet that implements such funtionality

https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum-server/blob/ce1b11d7f5f7a70a3b6cc7ec1d3e552436e54ffe/src/storage.py#L286

Comment: I just wonder if I can connect to one of those electrumx from my app, in other words to simulate electrum client in order to synchronise addresses?

Comment: Should be possible, yes.  Just study the API.

Comment: @vistore Does this answer your question?  If so, please accept the answer.